# how can i bring the two checkboxes next to each other in a table row?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried adding position and border by setting them to "0" in the css. But it didn't help. I want the two radio buttons to be next to each other. Now, there is a lot of space between them.

```html
<table>
  <tr class="table-row">
    <th>
      <p>
        <label>
          <input name="select_source" id="select-source-radio-btn" type="radio"/>
          <span>SELECT A SOURCE</span>
        </label>
      </p>
    </th>
    <th>
      <p>
        <label>
          <input name="select_source"  id="select-group-radio-btn" type="radio"/>
          <span>SELECT A GROUP</span>
        </label>
      </p>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Removing the paragraph elements would make a difference, though it's not that big with default browser formatting: http://jsfiddle.net/9r2Lgtne/1/

Comment: *"I want the two radio buttons to be next to each other."* With default formatting, they are (http://jsfiddle.net/9r2Lgtne/1/). Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: it worked with  adding a div row instead of using a table.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by a lot of space between them?  Currently you have a table of unknown width, with a row, which has 2 columns.  The 2 columns barring any other directives will be 50% width each.  If you table is 1000px wide, then each column will be 500px wide and thus you would have a lot of space between the checkboxes.

If you want them closer together, you would need to use some code to limit the table width.  Another option would be to use DIV's instead of a table and then have them be inline.

I would take a look at some things like "FLEX" grid, Bootstrap, etc. to get some good pointers on layout.